# Unity3D doesn't start anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine

my unity3d stop working I just have no idea what could it be. I've tried to reinstall different versions, tried to move all project to other directory. It always shows white window. Log file looks like this:

```
LICENSE SYSTEM [2017314 20:29:36] No start/stop license dates set
LICENSE SYSTEM [2017314 20:29:36] Next license update check is after 2016-03-23T05:59:23
LICENSE SYSTEM [2017314 20:29:36] 00325-95913-58456-AAOEM != 00325-95913-60258-AAOEM
LICENSE SYSTEM [2017314 20:29:36] QlkxNjEwQTAwMjAxMDI3 != QlkxNjEwQTAwMjAxMTM3
Built from '5.5/release' branch; Version is '5.5.2f1 (3829d7f588f3) revision 3680727'; Using compiler version '160040219'
OS: 'Windows 10  (10.0.0) 64bit' Language: 'en' Physical Memory: 8082 MB
BatchMode: 0, IsHumanControllingUs: 1, StartBugReporterOnCrash: 1, Is64bit: 1, IsPro: 0
Initialize mono
Mono path[0] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/lib/mono/2.0'
Mono path[2] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityScript'
Mono config path = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/etc'
Using monoOptions --debugger-     agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56796
```

I thought there is a problem with license conflict, but I was unable to find where this information is locating.

just installed version 5.0.0f4 and get "Unity activation" dialog which friezes with "Connecting to License Server message. Now, log file looks like this:

```
LICENSE SYSTEM [20170314 21:45:07] No start/stop license dates set
LICENSE SYSTEM [20170314 21:45:07] Next license update check is after 2016-03-23T05:59:23
LICENSE SYSTEM [20170314 21:45:07] 00325-95913-58456-AAOEM != 00325-95913-60258-AAOEM
LICENSE SYSTEM [20170314 21:45:07] QlkxNjEwQTAwMjAxMDI3 != QlkxNjEwQTAwMjAxMTM3
LICENSE SYSTEM [20170314 21:45:13] Opening https://license.unity3d.com/update/poll?cmd=9&tx_id=2b928f5cc862fc14f8cba451c89f1f4a
LICENSE SYSTEM [20170314 21:45:15] Received https://license.unity3d.com/update/poll?cmd=9&tx_id=2b928f5cc862fc14f8cba451c89f1f4a
LICENSE SYSTEM [20170314 21:45:15] Headers:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Status: 200 OK
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, 1.Remove/Uninstall Unity 2.Make sure that your computer system time is correct.Set the time. 3.Update your graphics card driver. 4.Delete everything in `C:\ProgramData\Unity`. 5.Now install the latest Unity version.

Comment: I just updated video driver (intel 520) and reinstalled latest version of unity - same problem. \Unity folder was deleted after uninstalling previous version. System time is ok because it automatically syncing all the time. IMHO, the problem is in conflicting of two licenses, but I can't find where this information is locating? I've deleted all unity application data and registry keys.

Comment: I suspected time because it says this on the log "Next license update check is after 2016-03-23T05:59:23". 2016 was last year that's a sign there is something wrong with your time. Anyways, I can't tell what's wrong and what to do next other than re-installing your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I had to delete all of unity. Install an older version. Open that. Then it said my license expired so I selected to use the free version. Then unity was able to work. Then I downloaded the most recent unity and it was cool.